# Change address error in Search console, can't pass 301 redirect confirmation

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect, change-address-tool

with a 301, I redirect friendsofcoffee.nl to misterbarish.nl.

I use the .htaccess file for the redirect with following code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^friendsofcoffee.example$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.friendsofcoffee.example$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ “https:\/\/misterbarish.example\/$1” [R=301,L]
```

Also tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^friendsofcoffee.example [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.friendsofcoffee.example [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://misterbarish.example/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Also tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.)friendsofcoffee.example [NC] OR RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^(.)friendsofcoffee.example [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://misterbarish.example/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also tried this

```
Redirect 301 / https://misterbarish.example/
```

But search console gives me the following error message. (Translated by Google translate.)

> Detour was not found
>   `https://www.friendsofcoffee.example/`

I tested the status code using https://httpstatus.io/

> User agent: Googlebot —> gives only 200, but no 301
>   User agent: Your browser —> gives only 200 and 301, so it technically works

What is going wrong?
I prepared this very thoroughly because I really don’t want to lose rankings.

Do you have an idea? Is it the coding in the .htaccess file?

[image: 1]

Comment: How did you set up the DNS, virtual hosts, and directories for the two sites?   Do the two sites point to the same place?   Does DNS point to the same server?  If so, do the two sites have separate directories, or do they share the same document root?

Comment: The DNS points to: different server and the IP addresses in DNS are totally different. DNS setting for friendsofcoffee.nl with 301 in htaccess: A: 34.240.160.162 | DNS setting for misterbarish.nl is A: 185.21.241.85 .                     I try to understand the why of your question? Why this could influence?

Comment: I see the redirect. Did you fix it?  I noticed your code used .example in the domain. The second snippet also had invalid quotes in it.

Comment: Hi Tony, the 301 redirects were always working. Only not validated by change address in Google search console. Yesterday I simplified the code `RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)friendsofcoffee\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://misterbarish.nl/$1 [R=301,L]`